# How to bind a TObjectList in Delphi

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I'm trying to figure out how to bind an object list to a list box. It seems all the Embarcadero samples bind to datasets.

It seems that I should use TBindList, but I cannot see how to link it to the TObjectsList. The SourceComponent property requires a component (not a list) and none of the events seem to make sense.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter components TListBindSourceAdapter and TObjectBindSourceAdapter enable LiveBindings with user defined TObjects.

Take a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415201555/https://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2012/12/11/31961) tutorial, it should help .

Comment: I actually got it working without the adapter, but this put me on the right track, thanks!